Cannot perform nslookup inside kubernetes pod
I have installed k3s to some raspberry pis using this ansible script however when i go to install anything, the pods cannot query the coredns pod
tom.mclean@node-0:~$ kubectl run coredns-test --image=alpine --restart=Never -i -t --command -- /bin/sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

/ # nslookup google.com 10.43.0.10
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

If I run it from the host machine, it works fine:
tom.mclean@node-0:~$ nslookup google.com 10.43.0.10
Server:         10.43.0.10
Address:        10.43.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.169.14
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4009:826::200e

tom.mclean@node-0:~$ nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 10.43.0.10
Server:         10.43.0.10
Address:        10.43.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.43.0.1

How can I debug why this is happening, and how can I fix it?
I have disabled the firewall:
tom.mclean@node-0:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

